# Identity Two-Factor Authentication alternatives

Tags: authentication, identity

One of my clients did not want to use any of the standard options (SMS or Email) for 2FA and I was wondering what others have implemented instead.

I felt that the site would be too vulnerable with just a username and password combination, even using max-attempts and timeouts.

A simple option that multiplies up the login uncertainty is by adding an additional security question  as part of the login page.

My answer is posted below

Answer (score 0):

Using the code-first approach in creating the user database, I added a set of security questions into my IdentityDbContext class.

```
public DbSet<SecurityQuestion> SecurityQuestions { get; set; }
```

This provides a simple list of questions such as "What is your favourite food". the questions should engender reasonably generic answers. The questions are added in the Configuration class Seed method

```
void AddSecurityQuestion(ApplicationDbContext db, string question)
    {
        db.SecurityQuestions.Add(new SecurityQuestion() { Question = question });
    }
```

A simple table is sufficient

```
public class SecurityQuestion
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    [DisplayName("Question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }
}
```

A field as added to the Identity User class. This will contain either null or  a hash of a security question and answer. For completeness, a property is added to check if the hash is present. The first time a user logs on, the hash is saved. On subsequent logons, the hash is checked

```
public string SecurityQuestion { get; protected set; } 


[NotMapped]
public bool HasSecurityQuestion
    {
        get
        {
            return this.SecurityQuestion != null;
        }
    }
```

Hashing uses the same code as the internal Identity methods and stores the seed and hash in the same string

```
public static string HashSecurityQuestion(string question, string answer)
{
    if (question == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Question is null");
    }

    if (answer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Answer is null");
    }

    string questionAndAnswer = question + "_" + answer;

    // random salt and hash in save result

    byte[] salt;
    byte[] buffer2;
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(questionAndAnswer, 0x10, 0x3e8))
    {
        salt = bytes.Salt;
        buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x31];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
}
```

A verification method is required

```
public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedSecurityQuestion, string question, string answer)
        {
            if (hashedSecurityQuestion == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (question == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Question is null");
            }

            if (answer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Answer is null");
            }

            string questionAndAnswer = question + "_" + answer;


            // has to retrieve salt
            byte[] buffer4;
            byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedSecurityQuestion);
            if ((src.Length != 0x31) || (src[0] != 0))
            {
                return false;
            }
            byte[] dst = new byte[0x10];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 1, dst, 0, 0x10);
            byte[] buffer3 = new byte[0x20];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0x11, buffer3, 0, 0x20);
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(questionAndAnswer, dst, 0x3e8))
            {
                buffer4 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
            }


        return buffer3.SequenceEqual(buffer4);
    }
```

In the login process, there is one extra step to verify the security question and answer are checked. The MVC View displays a drop down of questions and a textbox for an answer, both values for which are in the view model

```
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

        // if the user login is a success, check if a security question exists
        if (result == SignInStatus.Success && user.HasSecurityQuestion)
        {
            // security question exists, so check it
            if (!user.VerifySecrityQuestion(model.SecurityQuestion, model.SecurityQuestionAnswer))
            {
                result = SignInStatus.Failure;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Authy/Twilio Developer Evangelist here. There are a couple other options for additional security that you have:

**Enforce & encourage strong passwords**

This includes things like minimum length, showing a password "strength" [indicator](https://howsecureismypassword.net/), and including easy ways for people to use a password manager.

I compiled more details about recommendations for strong passwords:
https://github.com/robinske/betterpasswords

**One Time Passwords in the form of TOTP**

This is what you'd see with apps like [Authy](https://authy.com/) or [Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator). TOTP (time-based one time passwords) is a standard, you can read about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm).

[Authy has APIs to implement OTPs here.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/one-time-passwords)

**Push Authentication**

This is another form of 2FA that allows your user to "approve" or "deny" a login request in the form of a push notification. This is the most secure form of 2FA with a seamless user experience, [you can read more about how Authy does that here.](https://www.twilio.com/authy/features/push)

[Authy has APIs to implement push authentication here.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/push-authentications)

========

Note: security questions are a lot like additional passwords that can be more easily Googled, so I'd encourage your client to think about using a true second factor.

Comment: Strong passwords are required by the system. Users are not allowed to change them. They are given the password. They won't use 2FA. They won't use anything complicated for the users. I think what I have is acceptable and makes many hacks less likely at least. I could go for installed certificates but users log in from various devices

Comment: I've worked on this and hope to get them to use 2FA. Not quite there yet. I've had the Twilio NuGet package installed for some months so hopefully will go 2FA soon before the system goes live

Comment: Sweet - let me know if you have any questions if you get to that point!